# Can't get sort to work on foreach within wordpress snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I am trying to get this foreach to list the items in ABC order but I can't get it to work at all, the code is below, I tried using sort/usort on it but neither worked..

Can someone suggest a solution for this, please?

```
print '<div class="my-filter"><input type="checkbox" value=".property-column" id="all" checked /><label for="all" class="image-type" onclick="">' . __( 'All', 'wpestate-child' ) . '</label></div>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term = get_term( $term, 'property_image_type' );
    if( $term->name != '' ) {
        print '<div class="my-filter"><input type="checkbox" value=".property-column.' . $term->slug . '" id="' . $term->slug . '" /><label for="' . $term->slug . '" class="image-type" onclick="">' . $term->name . '</label></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the sort that you tried? what is the error or issue?

Comment: So how do you fill `$terms` thats where the sort probably ought to be

Comment: @NawedKhan No errors at all, it's just the same list as before...

Comment: So where are you sorting it? I don't see any code or effort to sort the array. How are you getting $terms ? When do you want to sort? onload or onclick of some button?